# Cross-platform solution like boost::uniform_smallint

Tags: c++, boost, random

I would like to start using boost::random in a widely cross platform application.
I was greatly attracted to boost by the fact that the specific implementation of boost::mt19937 is mandated by the specification.

However, I was saddened to learn that the boost distributions do not have the same guarantee and may vary from platform to platform.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.distributions

This means that if I want to have synchronized RNG's on different machines, I may not be able to use boost distributions as the tutorials show and as the designers seem to have intended.

Despite the caveat, I am still looking at boost::uniform_smallint. Here is the boost header:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/random/uniform_smallint.hpp

The key implementation details seem to appear in full in the boost header. Is there still actually a way that an implementer could cause the computation to have a different value on some platform? Should I actually be afraid to use this?

If I can't safely use this because of the warning in the library, what are my best alternatives? Should I just go back to using % directly on the rng output and hope that the quality of boost::mt19937 makes up for it?

Comment: This is a great question and I hope that someone more knowledgeable about boost than me can answer it. If you have 30 minutes to listen about random numbers, you might be interested in [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) on Microsoft's Channel 9.

Comment: Actually I already watched that and I would have posted the link as well but stackoverflow told me I don't have enough reputation to post more than two links. Glad to hear that I was on the right track though :) Actually it was only when I watched that video that I realized that the distributions may not be guaranteed to be cross platform... (although he is talking about C++ standard and not the boost standard iiuc)

Comment: can you use c++11 ? see [std::mt19937](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/)

Comment: http://numbercrunch.de/trng/ is what I use. It guarantees that its distributions consume exactly one random number from the underlying engine per number generated and also supports parallel RNGs.

Comment: @Jarod42: Unfortunately no, we are using c++98 and that is not likely to change in the near future, although we will eventually I guess. The issue is not about mt19937 though, which gives me an implementation guarantee in both boost and c++11 afaict, it's about the uniform int distribution objects.

Comment: While the implementation details may appear in full in the header, this does not mean that they cannot change between boost versions. Furthermore, if the base generator produced floating-point results, clearly there is room for difference between compilers and platforms, as the C++ standard does not completely define the behaviour of floating point numbers (and even when it does, there is still room for minor differences). (See the other comments for alternatives.)

Comment: @T.C. that's a splendid link. Thanks